# Java - Go to new url in new window/tab

Tags: java, url, tabs, web, new-window

I want to be able to use Java to tell it to go to X url when X browser is open/running (my lingo is terrible). (Firefox/Chrome/IE is already up, and I want it to go from the default page to let's say Twitter.)

Most of the solutions are using java.awt.Desktop to launch native browser with a url in it, but that isn't useful if I want to change the url later on. (Already on Twitter-Home Page, but want to go to Twitter-Contact Us afterwards.)

The other solutions I've seen involve using Selenium WebDriver, but I also need to eventually learn how to basically force the Java to read a long list of URLs off an excel and simply verify that url isn't dead, and then do this on the Native Android browser, for example. So the Selenium might not be the right choice. Granted, you can also tell me this is an awesome choice for this too if it truly is. I haven't really been exploring Selenium.

Sorry for asking such a basic question. Company wants QA Automation without training/hiring an Automation QA. My end goal (aside not getting canned), is to see if I can get a bunch of urls to load on specific browsers. I can sort of (praying) be able to do stuff with it afterwards.

Comment: On this specific page your question is not in scope but you can visit one of these to see if you get there an answer on your broad question or a better impression about existing solutions:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/
https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick would be to create an add-on( if you know javascript ) which will be quite similar in chrome and firefox (for IE I have no idea in my days it needed BHO) and send websocket commands from java to your addon. But this needs a java websocket server running where your addon will connect when the browser opens. Rest of communication can be carried upon the protocol lines of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple parts to your question.

1. Read urls from excel. 
   Use Apache POI to do the same. Selenium code can use the same.
2. Check that the urls are not dead.
   Use any java http client, (apache) to do that without even opening a browser. If the link is dead, it will be dead for all the browser.
3. Open the links in a multiple browsers.
   Selenium is perfect for this. I am assuming that after the page is loaded you have way of validating that the page is correct. Selenium is very powerful here.
4. Target native android browser too.
   I do not know of much difference between this and the previous question unless you are also testing site display based on browser size. The browser is more or less the same as chrome with webkit rendering engine.